# Birt Report Grouping

Tags: grouping, birt

I have 2 columns: *fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk* (Pilot)  and *fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk* (Co-Pilot).

When displaying data in the report I need to group based pilot name. He may be pilot or co-pilot.
It should come in same group. How can this grouping be achieved in a Birt report?

Comment: How should the report determine whether to use the Pilot or Co-Pilot for grouping - for example, will the Pilot be null when grouping by Co-Pilot? Alternatively, do you want separate rows in your report for Pilot and Co-Pilot?

Comment: thanks for your response, But here I have To achieve like below

Comment: thanks for your response, But here I have To achieve like (some time pilot(person) will pilot or co pilot in flight,that we storing in different column fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk (Pilot) and fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk (Co-Pilot) , then I am doing pilot summery report there I want group based on pilot(person) he may pilot or co pilot in flight but we need to display under his group and calculating duty time and etc.. for that perticuler pilot(Person) group

Comment: I think you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest amending your query from:

```
select fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk, fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk, ... from flight_Log_Table
```

to:

```
select fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk as group_By, ... from flight_Log_Table
union all
select fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk as group_By, ... from flight_Log_Table
```

then amend your report to group on the new group_By field in the query.

Comment: thank you very much, I Got solution but i have small issue global ordering

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column that combines the two in your SQL Query.

```
ISNULL ( fltrte_P1_Plt_Per_Id_Fk,  fltrte_P2_Plt_Per_Id_Fk  ) as 'Pilot'
```

If there is a value for P1 (Pilot) it will be in the new field 'Pilot', otherwise P2 (Co-Pilot) will the new field 'Pilot'

This solution works in BIRT 4.2 using a 2008 R2 database.

Answer (score 0):

Add the GROUP BY clause `Group by Pilot, Co-Pilot` to the end of your SQL query.